# Webm File Not Playing

Tags: javascript, mediastream, web-mediarecorder

I create a mediaRecorder to record video/audio and attach the recorded data, as an attribute, onto the canvas, like this:

```
    var options = { mimeType: 'video/webm;codecs=H264' };
    try {
        mediaStream = video.captureStream(); //console.log(mediaStream);
        mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(mediaStream, options);
        mediaRecorder.ondataavailable = function(e) { console.log('ondataavailable:'+e.data.size);
            mediaRecordedChunks.push(e.data);
            cvs.setAttribute('recordedChunks', mediaRecordedChunks);
        }; //console.log(mediaRecorder);
        mediaRecorder.onerror = function(err) { console.log('onerror:'+err.name); };
        //
        mediaRecordedChunks = [];
        mediaRecorder.start(1000); //1000 milliseconds per timeslice

    } catch(err) {
        console.log('err:'+err.name);     /* return the error name */
    };
};
```

I'm then reading the attribute and create a blob/file, like this:

```
if (localCanvas) {
    localCanvas.getContext('2d').clearRect(0, 0, localCanvas.width, localCanvas.height);
    //console.log('recordedChunks:'+localCanvas.getAttribute('recordedChunks')[0]);
    var blob = localCanvas.getAttribute('recordedChunks');
    //console.log('outBlob:'+outBlob);
    var binaryData = [];
    binaryData.push(blob);
    var url = (window.URL ? URL : webkitURL).createObjectURL(new Blob(binaryData, {type: 'video/webm;codecs=H264'}));
    var link = window.document.createElement('a');
    link.href = url;
    link.download = 'test_output.webm';
    var click = document.createEvent("Event");
    //click.initEvent('click', true, true);
    //link.dispatchEvent(click);
    link.click();
    window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
    link.remove();
    console.log('downloaded');
};
```

This clears the canvas and downloads the file to my machine.  But the file won't play.  I've tried different mime-types, but nothing working.  My ultimate goal is to have a playable video/audio file (ideally, a .mp4 file, but I understand that Chrome won't do that).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's completely unclear to me why you are doing this, but HTMLAttributes can only be strings, nothing else.

So when you do `cvs.setAttribute('recordedChunks', mediaRecordedChunks);` you are actually doing `cvs.setAttribute('recordedChunks', mediaRecordedChunks.toString());`, and since `mediaRecordedChunks` only contains a Blob object at this time, it will generate the string `"[object Blob]"`:

```js
const mediaRecordedChunks = [ new Blob([]) ];
const cvs = document.createElement( "canvas" );
cvs.setAttribute( "recordedChunks", mediaRecordedChunks );
console.log( cvs.getAttribute( "recordedChunks" ) );
```

And this what you do save in your file (you can try opening it in a text editor).
From this string, you won't be able to do anything related to the original chunks you did record.

---

The best is to make your saving code able to access the `mediaRecordedChunks` array directly, either by way of scoping, either by passing it as an argument to the function that holds the saving part.

```
// refactor your saving code to be a function
const saveMedia = ( chunks ) => {
    const blob = new Blob( chunks );
    //...
};
```

And then when you want to save, call it from the part where `mediaRecordedChunks` has been declared

```
saveMedia( mediaRecordedChunks );
```

If you absolutely want to use an attribute, **however bad it might be**, then create the *blobURI* from your recorder part and store this as the canvas attribute, though remember to revoke the previous one at each new *dataavailable* event.

```
//...
mediaRecorder.ondataavailable = function(e) {
  mediaRecordedChunks.push( e.data );
  const oldURL = cvs.getAttribute( 'recordedChunks' );
  URL.revokeObjectURL( oldURL );
  const newURL = URL.createObjectURL( mediaRecordedChunks );
  cvs.setAttribute( 'recordedChunks', newURL );
};
//...
```

And in your saving code,

```
if( localCanvas ) {
  const url = localCanvas.getAttribute( 'recordedChunks' );
  const link = window.document.createElement( 'a' );
  link.href = url;
  link.download = 'test_output.webm';
  document.body.append( link );
  link.click();
  link.remove();
}
```

Comment: This is excellent.  However, got the error "Failed to execute 'createObjectURL' on 'URL': No function was found that matched the signature provided".  I tried using; var newURL = (window.URL ? URL : webkitURL).createObjectURL(new Blob(mediaRecordedChunks, {type: 'video/webm;codecs=H264'}));.  Got a weird result - a playable .webm file with the just the filename on the screen.

Comment: @swabygw for the first error that means you didn't provide a Blob to `URL.createObjectURL()`. For the second, that sounds like a mystery... Can you try to provide an [mcve]?

Comment: Tested it again on a longer recording, they weren't errors after all.  The fix I put in for the first error worked, but the first few frames of the results were black screen - I thought it wasn't working, but video was produced after the first few frames.  Thanks for the help - this was a great solution.

Comment: @swabygw can u provide the implementation of this . i am facing same issue on windows 10 / ipad , tried the same code but i am able to see only black screen . i raised a similar question can u help link[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60965143/cant-preview-the-video-recorded-when-downloaded-recordrtc]

Comment: @Kaiido Can you help in acheiving this